# Proof of Identity Sidechain Proposals

Tags: multi-signature, sidechains, identity

I have seen various Proof of Identity Proposal that all required some degree of trust (to verify the person in physical possession of a Passport is also the owner of it for example).

Have their been any proposals that are completely trustless? Is so what methods have been suggested to cryptographically tie real life identities to identities on a Bitcoin sidechain in a trustless manner?

For example could we use multi sig to require a sufficient percentage of randomly selected scientists to verify that a DNA sample, video recording with face and Passport, certified birth certificate and PGP message received from a specific person matches the person trying to verify their identity on the blockchain?

Comment: Sounds to me like you are describing Web-of-trust. No need for a blockchain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"randomly selected scientists" - randomly selected by whom? And will you have scientists in every city across the world? And how will they get paid?

Ideas like that are practically impossible, and if you remember how PGP key signing parties ended up you'll understand why nobody is pursuing it.

The way Identifi is doing trust and reputation is one way to solve this. The other way is BIP75, which could be used to present a certificate signed by some certificate authority mutually accepted between you and the other parties. [This article goes into some detail about that](http://www.coindesk.com/blockchain-identity-company-netki-launch-ssl-certificate-blockchain/).